# How to extract data from javascript array using beautiful soup?

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup

The javascript file looks like this:

```
states_arr['Chittoor']= new Array(  "Kurnool (Abbas Nagar)# 9247001529             # H. No. 80-11/111, ; Beside ICICI Bank ATM, ;  Near Krishna Nagar Railway Gate, ; Abbas Nagar,  Kurnool.","Kurnool # 9247001530 # H. No. 46/694, Near Annapurna Hotel, Opp. Govt Hospital, Budawarpet, Kurnool. "  );
```

I want to extract the address from all the arrays in the js file that starts after the second '#' sign i.e.  " H. No. 80-11/111, ; Beside ICICI Bank ATM, ;  Near Krishna Nagar Railway Gate, ; Abbas Nagar,  Kurnool.",
                                    "H. No. 46/694, Near Annapurna Hotel, Opp. Govt Hospital, Budawarpet, Kurnool. "

The above complete javascript file is available at :
http://www.heteropharmacy.com/jScript/myScript.js

I am using BeautifulSoup for that matter and here is my incorrect code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
script = soup.find_all("script")
pattern = re.compile(r" (?<=[0-9]\s#\s).+")
while pattern.search(script):
    line1 = pattern.search(script)
    print line1
```

This file then needs to be converted into json format.

Comment: Does the answer below help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up the file with just python -

Assume `actual_file` to be your js file which you have just opened

```
# Split it by newline character and remove all lines which have less than 2 
# characters since our addresses are much longer
lines_of_js = [i.strip() for i in actual_file.split("\n") if len(i)>2]

# Now, remove lines with syntaxes of javascript and keep lines which have
# `#` in address. You may want to revisit this part for further fine tuning.
lines_with_address = [line for line in y if 
                            all([i not in line for i in '(<>={}'])
                            and 
                            ('#' in line)
                            ]
```

`lines_with-address` is now a list of such addresses

Split each line in this variable, split it by `#` and get the last item - this should be your address:

```
 In [94]: [line.split('#')[-1] for line in lines_with_address]
Out[94]: 
[' D.No. 5-9-24/66/1/a, Hill fort, ; Beside MLA quarters, ; Adarsh nagar, Hyderabad",',
 ' Plot No:23/A, Addagutta, ; Co-Opp.Housing Society Ltd. Opp. JNTU, ; HMT Hills Road, Kukatpally, Hyd",',
 ' Shop No.5, Plot No.86, ; Road No. 6, Vishnavy Recidency, ; Near AXIS Bank ATM, R.K.Puram,; Alkapuri Colony, Hyderabad.",',
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Python2.7

You don't need bs4 on this. Just use urllib2 or Py3k equivalent to read the source.

```
import re
import urllib2

dta = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.heteropharmacy.com/jScript/myScript.js').read()
final = [i[2:].replace('",', '').strip() for i in re.findall(r'# (?:[a-zA-Z]).+', dta)]
```

Sample Output (List):

`'H.No : 3-5-60/C-12 ; Opp. Andhra bank, ; Vivekananda Nagar Colony, ; Kukatpally, Hyderabad',
 "Flat No.G-6, Bhavya's Srinivasam, ; Opp. Sanghamitra School, ; Nizampet Road, Hyderabad",
 'H.No. 8-2-603/B/28, ; Opp. Hyderabad kababs, ; Road No-10, Banjara hills, Hyderabad',
 'H. No.1-55/C/9&10, Shop No. 9 & 10, ; Raghava Towers, Main Road, ; Madinaguda',
 'beside Cyberabad Police Commisionarate Office, ; Telecom Nagar, Gachibowli, ; Hyderabad"'`

Comment: Now how to further segregate the addresses in various fields like locality, landmark, city, state, etc. and store it in json?

Comment: first, make a new question. then second show your current code of that question you have.